# Slow internet speed on HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-w023dx model with Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265

Tags: internet-connection

I have a HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-w023dx model with Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 with Windows 10 Pro with all latest updates installed.

I have noticed that I cannot get more than 150 Mbps to 180 Mbps on a 1 Gb internet using WiFi (or even with using an Ethernet cable through a docking station connected to the USB 3 or USB C ports).

This is puzzling me as it means that whether Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 is used for WiFi connection or docking station is used for wired Ethernet, the speeds do not increase.

When the internet speed is tested on another laptop, I get download speeds of around 650 Mbps on WiFi. I have an ASUS RT-AX92U router connected through wired Ethernet and whose firmware has inbuilt speedtest and it gives speed of 700 Mbps to 800 Mbps which means that internet speed from ISP is not a problem.

I thought it could be some software configuration problem but when I do the speedtest on HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-w023dx using Windows Sandbox (meaning fresh and clean Windows installation) which is available in Windows 10 Pro, that too has same low speeds.

Any ideas on what could be causing this or if someone with similar experience sharing their views can help.

Comment: (1) Have you check whether the HP support assistant app can find more updates? (2) If installed, try uninstalling McAfee and HP Velocity?

Comment: HP and Intel has all drivers updated. 

To eliminate the cause if due to some software installation including security software, I used Windows Sandbox in Windows Pro for speedtest. Windows Sandbox provides a fresh clean installation of Windows Pro like a virtual machine and it was same slow speed.

Comment: HP support assistant app - All updates found are installed. No new updates found.
HP Velocity - Not installed
McAfee - Installed on host machine. Not installed in Windows Sandbox.

Will McAfee installed on host machine cause problems to Windows Sandbox ?

Comment: McAfee can possibly cause problems as it intercepts all API requests of Windows, which includes the Sandbox.